# What are the front running bots?

Tags: solidity, web3js, python, frontrunning

I've been seeing too many threads about this. I was curious about what are they how do they function? Is it basically an automated trading algorithm that just executes trades when a cryptocurrency is first released to the public?  If so why is this a problem, this can be easily done through web scraping and python, no? Can someone explain this to me with details all the youtube videos I watched so far are kind of vague

Comment: did you find any good sniper bot for uniswap?